# Does Angular Http Interceptor's "next.handle" method conform update subscriptions to observable?

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I have a service function that loads items from my backend. The data gotten from subscribing to this service is then used to populate a component. I have implemented an http interceptor to automatically refresh token once expired. The problem however, is that when next.handle is called, the component subscription to the initial service that was intercepted is not updated. The component only gets updated after page refresh. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: what is your subscription in component?

Comment: I have figured it out. Apparently I had no business tampering with the success response gotten from the interceptor. I was supposed to focus on just catching errors. Thank you.